# Laravel CRUD -- get account->name not account_id

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to edit a record but i want to see the name of the record, in my form if i use agency_id i get the id, but i want to use agency->name and get the name of that record, how do i do this in my controller?

My controller

```
public function index()
{
    $accounts = Account::all();
     return view('accounts',compact('accounts'));
}
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{
    $account=Account::find($id)->ith;
    $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Account has been updated');
    return view('accounts.edit',compact('account'));
}
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $account = Account::find($id);
    $account->update($request->all());
    $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Account successfully updated');
    return redirect('accounts');
}
public function show(Request $request, $id)
{
    $accounts= $request->all();
    return view('accounts.show',compact('accounts'));
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $account = new Account;
    $type = new Type;
    $agency = new Agency;
    $client = new Client;

    $agency->name = $request->name; $agency->save();
    $type->name= $request->name; $type->save();
    $client->name= $request->name; $client->save();
    $account->url= $request->url; $account->save();

    $account->client()->associate($client);
    $account->type()->associate($type);
    $account->agency()->associate($agency);
    $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'New account successfully created');
    return redirect('accounts');
}
```

And my form

```
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('Name', 'Name:') !!}
                {!! Form::text('client->name',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('Agency', 'Agency:') !!}
                {!! Form::text('agency->name',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('URL', 'Url:') !!}
                {!! Form::text('url',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you share the function of index and show ? to show the name of agency you need pass the variable to the view edit

Comment: Ok i've updated my post

Answer (score 2):

First you must have a method to edit the account:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $account = Account::find($id);

    return view('account.edit', ['account' => $account]);
}
```

This will allow you to fill the form, such as:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('name', $account->name, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
```

When you submit this form only then you'll update the account.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $account = Account::find($id);
    $account->fill($request->all())->save();

    return redirect('accounts')->with('alert-success', 'Account successfully updated');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{
        $account = Account::where('id' , $id)->first();
        // you can try also 
        // $account=Account::where('id' ,'=', $id)->first();
        $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Account has been updated');

        // make a test, so you can see if it work and return name of agency! like this: 

        return $account->name; 
        // if it return the name of agency it work! and you can try to return in your form!           

        return view('accounts.edit',compact('account'));


}
```

AND you can use like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', $account->name, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```